# Old Console and VisualForce Pages

Tags: visualforce, console, cross-domain

I have a relatively simple Visualforce page that just uses the apex:detail to show the cases detail on the page. With that comes the out of the box change owner and change record type links and related record links. None of the links work due to the following security error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://c.myinstance.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://myinstance.salesforce.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I have scoured the internet for a solution to this problem and have tried the suggestions for using the salesforce console integration toolkit. However, even the very first example in the SCIT guide does not work. When in the console and using the links on the example page I get the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Listener' of undefined iframeinterface.js:1
>   Sfdc.xdomain.IframeInterface.handleOnload iframeinterface.js:1
>   window.onload"

When not in the console I get the security error like the initial issue with a basic Visualforce page with standard links in the console.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

On a side note, I have been able to get simple functions to work, like testIsInConsole.

Comment: Hello, @jjbennett530, I don't think you're doing anything wrong in this case. I recommend you log this as a case with Salesforce Support and pursue it as a possible bug.

Comment: I did and they said I needed premier support for development questions :(

Comment: That's ridiculous... can you post the details (including case number) of the case you logged? I assume you'd have written out detailed instructions for reproducing the problem.

Comment: Case #10745267; Case Description: We are using the legacy console and have a visualforce page overriding the cases view page. We are getting the following error when attempting to use the hyperlinks on the page(standard hyperlinks, like change recordType and change owner) using the apex:detail page:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VFState.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: SfdcCmp is not defined Zen.js:8
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "instance" from accessing a frame with origin "instance". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. desktopMain.js:6"

Comment: Response: I am Nehal from Salesforce Developer Support Team and would like to inform you that Developer support is currently available only to our premier customers and partners. We apologize for any impact this may be having on you.
We support our standard customers through the developer support boards at https://developer.salesforce.com/. If you have a developer support question, are looking for technical documentation, best practices, code samples and other ways to speed your development time. We have dedicated support representatives that work the boards to answer questions.

Comment: @MartyC. - par for the course. sfdc support is useless unless you pay, even reporting bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenny B,

I have a workaround that works for me. You can below code inserting into your visualforce page that overrides your standard page.

```
apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"

script type="text/javascript"
var accId = '{!account.ID}';
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) 
{
    window.location.href = '/' + accId + '?nooverride=1&isdtp=mn'; 
} 
script
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to just include the apex:detail tag and not recreate the standard page in vf.

Comment: I meant you can insert the above code in the same page where you have detail tag. just make sure script tags are properly written. Let me know if you still have questions. I also had the same issue as you had. I just worked out this today. Works great for me.

Comment: There are links on the detail page, I believe it was the change owner link on the standard page layout.

Comment: Jenny, it will work for all links. The key is even though the standard view page is overriden by visualforce page, by inserting the code I provided, you will  not override the standard page with visualforce page in the salesforce console(only). Thus, all your links including change owner will work normal as in a standard view page. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry didn't look at it that close, I'll have to test that out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can log a case and ask the SF support to "Disable clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages"

This is a setting located at Setup > Security Settings > Session Settings. You have to log a ticket and can't change it on your own. Fortunately you'll need no premier to get it done. And it's reversible, support can change it back.

But please keep in mind that this setting is for a reason and disabling it could reduce the security level. So please see this just as an interim solution.

Comment: I have been working with someone at salesforce and they don't believe disabling clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages will fix the issue and do not recommend us disabling it. So far it looks like I will not be able to use the apex:detail tag on visualforce pages if they appear in the console.

Comment: You can try if it helps or not in a sandbox or developer org. I'm pretty sure it will help. But as said earlier, security impacts has to be considered on production orgs.

Comment: I went ahead and had them disable it in our sandbox and tested it out and unfortunately it didn't make a difference.